# Camera preview processing on Android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

I'm making a line follower for my robot on Android (to learn Java/Android programming), currently I'm facing the image processing problem: the camera preview returns an image format called YUV which I want to convert to a threshold in order to know where the line is, how would one do that?

As of now I've succeeded getting *something*, that is I definitely can read data from the camera preview and by some miracle even know if the light intensity is over or under a certain value at a certain area on the screen. My goal is to draw the robot's path on an overlay over the camera's preview, that too works to some extent, but the problem is the YUV management.

[image: Galaxy Nexus Screenshot]

As you can see not only the dark area is drawn sideways, but it also repeats itself 4 times and the preview image is stretched, I cannot figure out how to fix these problems.

Here's the relevant part of code:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // camera setup
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    for(int i=0; i<sizes.size(); i++)
    {
        Log.i("CS", i+" - width: "+sizes.get(i).width+" height: "+sizes.get(i).height+" size: "+(sizes.get(i).width*sizes.get(i).height));
    }

    // change preview size
    final Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(8);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width, cs.height);

    // initialize image data array
    imgData = new int[cs.width*cs.height];

    // make picture gray scale
    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    // change display size
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (int) (mSurfaceView.getWidth()*cs.height/cs.width);
    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);

    LayoutParams overlayParams = (LayoutParams) swOverlay.getLayoutParams();
    overlayParams.width = mSurfaceView.getWidth();
    overlayParams.height = mSurfaceView.getHeight();
    swOverlay.setLayoutParams(overlayParams);

    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }

    // callback every time a new frame is available
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            // create bitmap from camera preview
            int pixel, pixVal, frameSize = cs.width*cs.height;
            for(int i=0; i<frameSize; i++)
            {
                pixel = (0xff & ((int) data[i])) - 16;
                if(pixel < threshold)
                {
                    pixVal = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    pixVal = 1;
                }
                imgData[i] = pixVal;
            }

            int cp = imgData[(int) (cs.width*(0.5+(cs.height/2)))];

            //Log.i("CAMERA", "Center pixel RGB: "+cp);
            debug.setText("Center pixel: "+cp);

            // process preview image data
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);


            int start, finish, last;
            start = finish = last = -1;
            float x_ratio = mSurfaceView.getWidth()/cs.width;
            float y_ratio = mSurfaceView.getHeight()/cs.height;

            // display calculated path on overlay using canvas
            Canvas overlayCanvas = overlayHolder.lockCanvas();
            overlayCanvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);

            // start by finding the tape from bottom of the screen      
            for(int y=cs.height; y>0; y--)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<cs.width; x++)
                {
                    pixel = imgData[y*cs.height+x];

                    if(pixel == 1 && last == 0 && start == -1)
                    {
                        start = x;
                    }
                    else if(pixel == 0 && last == 1 && finish == -1)
                    {
                        finish = x;
                        break;
                    }
                    last = pixel;
                }
                //overlayCanvas.drawLine(start*x_ratio, y*y_ratio, finish*x_ratio, y*y_ratio, paint);
                //start = finish = last = -1;
            }
            overlayHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(overlayCanvas);
        }
    });
}
```

This code generates an error sometimes when quitting the application due to some method being called after `release`, which is the least of my problems.

---

**UPDATE:**

Now that the orientation problem is fixed (CCD sensor orientation) I'm still facing the repetition problem, this is probably related to my YUV data management...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your surface and camera management looks correct,   but I would doublecheck that camera actually accepted preview size settings ( some camera implementations reject some settings silently)

As you are working with portrait mode, you have to keep in mind that camera does not give a fart about prhone orientation -  its coordinate origin  isdetermined by CCD chip and is always to right corner  and  scan direction is from top to bottom and right to left   - quite different from your overlay canvas.  ( But if you are in landscape mode, everything is correct ;) ) - this is certaily source of odd drawing result

Your threshloding is bit naive and not very usefull in real life - I would suggest adaptive threshloding. In our javaocr project ( pure java, also has android demos )  we implemented efficient sauvola binarisation (see demos):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Performance  binarisation can be improved to work only on single image rows (patches welcome)

Issue with UV part of image is easy -   default forman is NV21, luminance comes first
and this is just byte stream,  and you do not need UV part of image at all (look into demos above)

Comment: Thank you for the CCD tip, it was indeed the problem, now how about the repetition, this is definitely related to my YUV management. Once I get it working I'll optimize it with dynamic threshold.

Comment: ...  comendted about liminance issue